# External stylesheet vs. JavaScript-added style tag

Tags: javascript, css, stylesheet

I have multiple widgets that can be added to various Web pages. Each comes with its own stylesheet:

```
<link type="text/css" href="http://mySite/widget1.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mySite/widget1.js"></script>
```

The stylesheets are specific to each widget and very short (5 to 10 declarations).

I am considering having the stylesheet created dynamically within the script, for two reasons:

- I find it painful to maintain two separate files
- replacing two http requests with one should bring performance improvements

Something like this, inserted in widget1.js:

```
var stylesheet=document.createElement("style");
stylesheet.innerHTML="#slideshow{width:500px;...";
etc...
```

Anything wrong with this? This sounds like a good idea to me, but when I look at other examples (like jQuery plugins) the css and js are always in separate files.

Comment: Note that you'd still have two requests, because when you add that link element to the DOM, it will go and request it. If you only have 5-10 declarations, maybe you can just do them in-line and not worry about a stylesheet at all.

Comment: @BrianGlaz sorry, I immediately realized that my example was all wrong, and corrected the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final choice was to create the stylesheet from within the script.

Besides reducing the number of http requests, the major benefit is actually that you can tweak the stylesheet before injecting it. This is especially useful for widgets, as you can adjust a class name, a color or a size at runtime.

At a larger scale, this is what some libraries like LESS and SASS are doing.

Answer (score 3):

That won't help at all with the HTTP requests. Adding a link to an external stylesheet with JavaScript is still going to demand an HTTP request to fetch it.

You would probably be better off using something like [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) to merge and minify the stylesheets for all the widgets you use into a single CSS file. Then include it in every page and let browsers cache it.

Comment: sorry, I immediately realized that my example was all wrong, and corrected the question.

Answer (score 1):

> replacing two http requests with one should bring performance improvements

If you have your CSS in its own file, the browser can cache it, thus improving performance.  Having JavaScript creating it will wind up making a bigger JS file, and it (the CSS) can't be cached.  Also, JavaScript will have to generate the CSS, thus lowering performance.

Comment: Even with caching, there will be a http request, right? Because of the stylesheet size, I am more worried about the time wasted with the http request than the load time.

Comment: Pretty sure if it's cached, there's no HTTP request, or it just gets the headers, not the data.  Unless your server is really slow at responding, then the "time wasted" won't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a new style element, 
why not put the code for it in the js widget file it affects?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea (poorly explained in the question...). The code that creates the style element would go into widget1.js. I have corrected the post.